# Cursors are shifted on iOS

Tags: mobile-safari, ios11, mobile-chrome

Could anybody help me?
I have an issue related with shifted cursors. Problem is only on in chrome and safari on iOS 11. It looks like

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix the iOS 11 input element in fixed modals bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567233/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be related to a WebKit bug [wrong caret position for input field inside a fixed position parent on iOS 11](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176896) demonstrated by [Eirik Luka](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8).

**Possible workarounds:**

- Stretch the dialog to the edges of the window, hiding the rest of the content in the body with `display: none`
- Change the container from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`
- Do not use modal dialogs

Comment: Thanks, I realized the second variant.