# iOS 11 Fixed Modal Bug

Tags: javascript, ios, css, reactjs, safari

I have a fixed modal that has some scrollable content and some input fields. I'm having an issue where I focus on an input field, which pops up the keyboard, and then scroll.
It seems the DOM elements are misaligned compared to what is actually rendered on the screen.
See the screenshot - the highlighted area should be where the continue button is. This means that I can't click continue as expected.

I thought this might be the issue, however the fix doesn't seem to have worked fully (still broken on iPhone X).

Has anyone else run into this issue or got a fix?

[hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8](http://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8)[image]

Comment: Update: This has been confirmed as an iOS bug and will be fixed in an upcoming release. see here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176896

Comment: Apple is in no hurry to fix this.

Comment: The fix has been confirmed in the 11.3 beta build. So it's just a waiting game until that makes its full release.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've experienced this bug. Although not perfect, and it won't work for every site, cursor is still a little out, but it's at least within the input field and you can skip between fields... here's my fix...

It also helps to make the modal 100% width.

I've been following this thread for updates of a fix in iOS itself, seems like it's getting close - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176896

```
@media
only screen /* iPhone X */
and (device-width : 375px) 
and (device-height : 812px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3),
only screen /* iPhone 8 */
and (device-width : 375px) 
and (device-height : 667px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2),
only screen /* iPhone 8 Plus */
and (device-width : 414px) 
and (device-height : 736px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3),
only screen /* iPhone 7 */
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px), 
only screen /* iPhone 7 Plus */
and (min-device-width : 414px)
and (max-device-width : 736px),
only screen /* iPhone 6 */
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px),
only screen /* iPhone 6 Plus */
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px),
only screen /* iPhone 5 & 5S */
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px),
only screen /* iPad */
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px),
only screen /* iPad 3 and 4 */
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen /* iPad 1 and 2 */
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
only screen /* iPad Mini */
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
html,body {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
overflow: auto !important;
height: 100% !important;
}
}
```

Comment: I've actually been in contact with some webkit/apple devs on that ticket, and they confirmed their fix will resolve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ThatTobMate - did they give you any idea on when it will be fixed? I've been working on resolving this bug for our site for over a day now.

Comment: @NealJones Hey they've claimed it's fixed but they don't have a schedule on release.

See here https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=176896

Answer (score 0):

**This solution helped me to fix in any IOS model.**

[How to fix the iOS 11 input element in fixed modals bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567233/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug/49146250#49146250)

I already explained in above urL but I will explain here also just in case...

First thing target only IOS devices with this code.

```
//target ios
var isMobile = {
  iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  }
}
if(isMobile.iOS()) { 
  jQuery('body').addClass('apple-ios');
}
```

then put this code in your css:

```
body.apple-ios.modal-open {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
```

If you are using wordpress and cache plugin, you need to empty all the cache.

Hope this help you.