# CSS 'transform' vs 'position: absolute'

Tags: css

What is difference between

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

**and**

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

?

What is better to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS translation vs changing absolute positioning values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100747/css-translation-vs-changing-absolute-positioning-values)

Comment: 1) Based on its parent (if relative), else screen. 2) Based on itself, i.e. moved here and there based on its own width/height.

Answer (score 2):

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

This object is placed according to the `parent` element. It will change according the `parent`'s position.

---

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

This object is based on itself. If the object is moved, it will translate according its new position.

---

Although both can show the same result in initial format, you will notice clear differences when styling `parent` elements.