# Animate an element to left and right like a yoyo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I have a red box as the element to animate.

Here is a simple representation of how I want to animate the red box.

[image]

Here is a try but as you see the anchor point of the movement is at the left of the box no the center as I wish to be:

```css
.yo-yo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red; 
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: yo-yo 0.5s infinite alternate;  /* Animation speed and type */
}

/* Animation beginning and ending */
@keyframes yo-yo {
  from {  left: 0 }
  to {  left: 20px }
}
```

```html
<span class="yo-yo"></span>
```

Here is the script tag of that specific version of TweenMax:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-DkPsH9LzNzZaZjCszwKrooKwgjArJDiEjA5tTgr3YX4E6TYv93ICS8T41yFHJnnSmGpnf0Mvb5NhScYbwvhn2w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This has been answered [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/25217-animate-an-element-to-left-and-right-like-a-yoyo-smoothly/?tab=comments#comment-121654).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [progress](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes2) instead of just simply declaring a `from` and `to` in the keyframes rule

Something like this would suffice. If you want a repeating animation then just add a `infinite` before linear

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

.yo-yo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: yo-yo 2s linear;
  /* Animation speed and type */
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


/* Animation beginning and ending */

@keyframes yo-yo {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  75% {
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="yo-yo"></span>
```

Comment: @Sara Ree You could try adding a small delay before repeating the animation

Comment: So there is no solution with easing?

Comment: @SaraRee i dont believe that easing will solve the jank

Comment: @SaraRee solved it, the jank is caused due to the fact that the default padding and margin that the document has, try running again

Comment: @SaraRee added easing too

Answer (score 0):

Your making it too complicated. Just use the percentages in `@keyframes`, and use `transform: translateX(number)` like so:

```
@keyframes yo-yo {
  0% {transform: translateX(0); }
  25% { transform: translateX(-20px); }
  75% { transform: translateX(20px);  }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px);  }
}
```

You should try to use `transform` instead of giving positions. For a better understanding, checkout this link [CSS translation vs changing absolute positioning values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100747/css-translation-vs-changing-absolute-positioning-values).

Comment: ok, but there is issue in your code. a jerking movement when repeating the animation...

Comment: try using 2% instead of 0% and 98% instead of 100%. Does it still happen?@SaraRee

Answer (score -1):

You can use animation with `infinite normal linear`.  If you remove `infinite` from animation then it will stop after one iteration. Your animation is divided into 5 parts. `0, all the way right, 0, all the way left, 0`. So start changing the left position from `0%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%`.

```css
.yoyo-container{
  background-color: #DEEBF7;
  padding:12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 16px;
  
  
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.yo-yo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red; 
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: yo-yo 2s infinite normal linear;  /* Animation speed and type */
}

/* Animation beginning and ending */
@keyframes yo-yo {
   0% {transform: translateX(0); }
  25% { transform: translateX(50%); }
  50% { transform: translateX(0);  }
  75% { transform: translateX(-50%);  }
  100% { transform: translateX(0);  }
}
```

```html
<div class="yoyo-container">
<span class="yo-yo"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can't we use an easing?

Comment: `linear` is the `animation-timing-function`. You can try with `ease`, `ease-in`, `ease-in-out` etc.. but `linear` fits on your requirement

Comment: when you say easing, you mean tweenmax easing?

Comment: Please have a look at this codepen: I mean easing like this not a linear movement.: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/poyEVWb